# pandas group by slower, how to optimize it

Tags: python, r, pandas, python-3.6

I have following table with 518562 records and 11 columns

tableA

```
------------------------------------------- 
X (datetime object)| Y (String Object)| Z  ..
-------------------------------------------
2016-11-29 14:32:26| 30123891912AI    | 1  ..
```

.....

I want to group by Y and find newest entry from table

I have following code which is doing it

```
tableA.groupby("Y", as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g[g["X"] == g["X"].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It takes about 208 Second to compute.

I have similar code for R which takes about 35 Second, which is as follows:

```
tableA %>% group_by(Y) %>% filter(X == max(X))
```

Do you know how to optimize code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `python` ,If you need slice the max row , you can get rid of `groupby`

```
df.sort_values(['Y','X']).drop_duplicates(['Y'],keep='last')
```

Or

```
idx = df.groupby(['Y'])['X'].transform(max) == df['X']
df[idx]
```

---

In you `R` code

```
tableA %>% group_by(Y) %>% slice(which.max(X))
```

Or

```
df=df[order(df$Y,df$X),]
df[!duplicated(df$Y,fromLast = T),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `data.table` in R which may be the fastest.

```
require(data.table)

setDT(df1)

df[,max(X), keyby = .(Y)]
```

Using simple dummy data (n=500k):

```
df1 <- data.table(a=sample(1:10,500000,replace=T),b=sample(1:5,500000,replace=T))

system.time(df1[,max(b),keyby=.(a)])

   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01
```

Compared to `dplyr`:

```
system.time(df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% slice(which.max(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.00    0.26
```